# How to read from a csv file in zip folder and save data from csv file in database?

Tags: python, csv, zip

```
  import glob
  import os
  import csv
  import zipfile 
  from io import StringIO
  for name in glob.glob('C:/Users/RAMESH SANTHA/Downloads/download-NIFTY 50-01012020.zip'):
      base = os.path.basename(name)
      filename = os.path.splitext(base)[0]

  datadirectory = 'C:/Users/RAMESH SANTHA/Downloads/'
  dataFile = filename
  archive = '.'.join([dataFile, 'zip'])
  fullpath = ''.join([datadirectory, archive])   
  csv_file = '.'.join([dataFile, 'csv']) #all fixed

  filehandle = open(fullpath, 'rb')
  zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filehandle)
  data = StringIO.StringIO(zfile.read(csv_file)) 
  reader = csv.reader(data)
  for row in reader:   
     print (row)
```

I tried following code to read data from zip folder which contains csv file and print rows but got error:

```
data = StringIO.StringIO(zfile.read(csv_file)) 

AttributeError: type object '_io.StringIO' has no attribute 'StringIO'
```

Comment: So, what I would do, is with Python unzip the folder to a temp location, then iteratively read all csv files in that resulting folder, do whatever processing you need with that file, then when you are done, delete that temp folder.  The processing of the data though is subjective because I dont know how your DB is defined, or how you want the data to be preserved.  If this is a valid workflow I can write it up for you, but you do see my unknowns.  If you can edit the question to clarify said unknowns then we can work towards a better answer.

Comment: there is no `StringIO.StringIO` but `io.StringIO` (if you use `import io`). But if you uses `from io import StringIO` then you need only `data = StringIO(...)`

Comment: BTW: `pandas.read_csv()` can read directly from `.zip` file.

Comment: I think you overcompicated code using `glob` It seems you don't have zip folder but  normla zip file and you could use your path directly in `open()` - `open('C:/Users/RAMESH SANTHA/Downloads/download-NIFTY 50-01012020.zip')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `StringIO.StringIO()` but `io.StringIO()`

```
import io

data = io.StringIO(...)
```

With your import it will be even without `io.`

```
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(...)
```

---

**BTW:** I think you overcomplicated code using `glob` and `join()`. And you can use filename directly with `ZipFile` without `open()`

```
import os
import csv
import zipfile 
import io

zip_fullname = 'C:/Users/RAMESH SANTHA/Downloads/download-NIFTY 50-01012020.zip'
zip_file = os.path.basename(zip_fullname)
csv_file = zip_file.replace('.zip', '.csv')

print(zip_file)  # download-NIFTY 50-01012020.zip
print(csv_file)  # download-NIFTY 50-01012020.csv

zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_fullname)
data = io.StringIO(zfile.read(csv_file).decode('utf-8')) # bytes needs to be converted to string
reader = csv.reader(data)
for row in reader:   
    print(row)
```

But with `pandas` it should be even simpler

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/RAMESH SANTHA/Downloads/download-NIFTY 50-01012020.zip')

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for solving issue.The above code worked but with small correction in line     data = io.StringIO(zfile.read(csv_file)) which should be replaced by                                  
encoding = 'utf-8'                                                                                                     data = io.StringIO((zfile.read(csv_file)).decode(encoding)) because Zfile.read(csv_file) returns bytes which needs to be converted to string using decode method.

Comment: @rameshsantha you are right, I didn't test it. It should work also with `.decode()` without `encoding = 'utf-8'` because it should use `utf-8` as default value. At least on Linux (which I use) it uses `utf-8` as default.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the script you getting error opening the csv file from zip file.  Below is python 3 code that I have working for a zip file having few csv's. The directory to extract should exist before you run the script

```
import zipfile
path_to_zip_file='/tmp/test1.zip' # Assuming this file exist , This path is from mac, but should work for windows as well'
directory_to_extract_to='/tmp/extract/' # Assuming this directory already exist
import csv,os
import codecs
import glob

with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(directory_to_extract_to)


for file in glob.glob(directory_to_extract_to+'*.csv'):
    path = os.path.join(directory_to_extract_to,file)
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(f, 'utf-8'))

        # Below code is print them as arrays
        # for row in reader:
        #     print(row)

        # Reading rows as ordered dictionary
        dictReader = csv.DictReader(codecs.iterdecode(f, 'utf-8'))
        for row in dictReader:
             print(row)
```